# IF ELSE using MID in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to form a formula using `IF`, `ELSE` and `MID` in excel

VB241111NS

I want to increment the above string.

VB24111 2 NS
VB24111 3 NS
....

but when it reaches9 it increments to 10, that is,

VB24111 10 NS

I want to restrict the total length of the string to 10. So I believe I need to make a formula, when I find a 9 I need to alter it. This is the formula i came up with.

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(J2,7), MID(J2,8,1)+1, RIGHT(J2,2))
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to increment 6 digit number like that:

[image]

all you need is to change the lengths of substrings extracted in each part of your formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(J2,2), MID(J2,3,6)+1, RIGHT(J2,2))
```

Same formula with `&` concatenation operator:

```
=LEFT(J2,2) & MID(J2,3,6)+1 & RIGHT(J2,2)
```